# How to fix TypeError: getText() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in python?

Tags: python, selenium

**I'm calling methods of class reuse in this class **
'''

```
from behave import *
from Functions_Orange.reuse import Reuse
from Resources import Locator

class Orange:


 @given('Navigate to organeHRM')
 def Navigate_loginPage(context):
    print("Testing======Test \n")
    print(Locator.Locator_UserName)
    Reuse.sendText(Locator=Locator.Locator_UserName,Text=Locator.UserName)
    Reuse.sendText(Locator=Locator.Locator_passWord,Text=Locator.Password)
```

'''

**This is reuse class where i have created method**

```
    from Resources.Driver import *
class Reuse(Driver):
    y = Driver()
    y.intialise()
    def markElement(self,Locator):
      self.intialise().find_element_by_xpath(Locator)
    def click(self,Locator):
      self.intialise().find_element_by_xpath(Locator).click()
    def getText(self,Locator):
       self.intialise().find_element_by_xpath(Locator)
       return self.y.__getattribute__("text")
    def sendText(self,Locator,Text):
        self.intialise().find_element_by_xpath(Locator).send_keys(Text)
```

Comment: `r = Reuse() -- r.getText("locator")` ?  -- You dont show up where you are calling `getText()` -- my guess is that you are not calling it on an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate Reuse and call the method on that object.

Something along the lines :

```
@given('Navigate to organeHRM')
def Navigate_loginPage(context):
    print("Testing======Test \n")
    print(Locator.Locator_UserName)
    r = Reuse()
    r.sendText(Locator=Locator.Locator_UserName,Text=Locator.UserName)
    r.sendText(Locator=Locator.Locator_passWord,Text=Locator.Password)
```